# How can I trigger a single error handler with nested promises?

Tags: node.js, promise, q

Why don't any of the `deferred.reject()` calls trigger the `.fail()` handler at the end? How can I trigger a single error handler with nested promises? I need nested promises for the closure.

When I trigger the reject on `d1`, it still goes all the way to the resolution/rejection of `d2`. If I add `.fail()` to the block of `d1`, then it does catch the rejection. But that is what I'm trying to avoid, a `.fail()` handler for every nested promise.

```js
var Q = require('q');

somePromise().then(function (v1) {

  var d1 = Q.defer();

  asyncFunc1(v2, function (err, v3) {
    if (!v3) 
      d1.reject(new Error('error'));
    else
      d1.resolve(true);

    return d1.promise.then(function (promise1Kept) {
      var d2 = Q.defer();
      asyncFunc2(v4, function (err, v5) {
        if (!v5)
          d2.reject(new Error('error'));
        else
          d2.resolve(true);
      });
      return d2.promise.then(function (promise2Kept) {
        console.log('end of promise chain');
      });
    });
  });
}).fail(function (err) {
  console.log('Error!');
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: What output do you get when you run this ?

Comment: @user568109 Added more details and fixed some typos.

Comment: Can you tell why you don't want a `fail`? It is necessary (this or a `then`) to execute the errorhandler. There is no errorhandler by default. It will just reach error and stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix callbacks and promises or use deferreds. As you noticed it's really easy to mess the chain up when you need to manually do everything.

```
var Q = require('q');
var func1 = Q.denodeify(asyncFunc1);
var func2 = Q.denodeify(asyncFunc2);

somePromise().then(function (v1) {
  return func1(v2);
}).then(function (v3) {
  if (!v3) throw new Error("error");

  return func2(v4);
}).then(function (v5) {
  if (!v5) throw new Error("error");

  console.log("end of promise chain");
}).fail(function (err) {
  console.log('Error!');
  console.log(err);
});
```